# What's a word that suggests having very long ears?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for an adjective that describes a living being as having very long ears (rabbit, donkey, etc.) preferably ending in "-uous".

Comment: "A mule is an animal with long floppy ears..."

Comment: Not very relevant, but in Japanese it's "fukumimi" (福耳), which translates literally to "lucky ears". Buddha is depicted as having long ears, so it's thought that people with long ears have good fortune. One of those words that you wouldn't think exists.

Comment: There's a difference between having long drooping ear lobes like the Buddha and having a lengthened [helix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix_(ear)). Surely there is a medical term for either.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [*macrotous*](http://www.wordnik.com/words/macrotous).

Comment: Go ahead, see if you can work that into a conversation.

Comment: I've never come across *macrotous* before, and to be honest I'd be lucky to have understood it without a pretty good context. *Macrotic* would do it for me, since I'm good with *otic* for *of the ear*. But apparently *macrosis* applies to any swollen / enlarged tissue or body part, with no particular suggestion of that being the ears.

Comment: I love this site! :D

Comment: I don't agree with using words that no one but Merriam-Webster will understand; especially when there are [perfectly good](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18764/18766#18766) alternatives.  Perhaps it's just the programmer in me, but this seems like the opposite of user-friendly (or should I say, [discommodious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Discommodious)?)

Comment: @BlueRaja: I still remember Thomas Pynchon using musaceous (banana-like) at the beginning of Gravity's Rainbow, and then, after I waited for years to use it, someone finally asked me: "How's that banana?"

Answer (score 14):

You should probably just go with "long-eared" — I don't think there are any specific terms meaning that, except possibly scientific ones with Latin roots.

Comment: Long-eared is attested in my dictionary for at least one animal species, the ***“long-eared bat”***

Comment: "-uous" suffix?

Comment: @Billare: "preferably ending in ..."

Comment: @Billare: you can always go with *long-earuous*, or *earuous* for short.

Comment: _Auritus -a -um_: with ears, long-eared, having long ears

Answer (score 9):

Huh, you might say the animals have **pendulous** ears.  That emphasizes the weight of the ears, as well as suggesting they hang in a droopy fashion.

[image: Two super cute bunnies in a basket]

Comment: rabbit and donkeys ears are not pendulous, they rise up from their base!

Comment: @F'x I have seen floppy rabbit ears before, but yeah, I was worried about that one.  But donkeys? Really? Time to Google...

Comment: I believe there is a type of rabbit called "Lop-eared" or "a lop", which does in fact have pendulous ears. I recall a young kids book about one. "Leo the Lop".

Comment: @mickeyf: Good call on _[lop-eared](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1264346#m_en_us1264346)_: "(of an animal) having ears that droop down by the sides of the head:
_a lop-eared mule_." Answer-worthy.

Answer (score 3):

**Hyperotic** could be construed to mean "over-eared" [(otic)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/otic?show=0&t=1301592528), though the folks at [Urban Dictionary have other ideas about the definition.](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Hyperotic)

Answer (score 0):

There's always "asinine".  Although that does imply dim-witted, as well as visually reminiscent of a donkey, which is maybe more of an implication than you wanted!

Answer (score -1):

How about **Vulpine** - of or relating to a fox. "He had vulpine ears"

Comment: ...or vulcan ;-)

Comment: There are some long eared foxes like the Fennec Fox, but fox ears for the most commonly known species such as the red fox are not very long in proportion to other animals in my opinion, and I do not think any Fox species has ears as long as a donkey's or a rabbit's.